# How to stop Mouse Out event on Flex Canvas firing for child elements

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, canvas, mouseout

I am using a Canvas itemRenderer for a container I use to display images. See pseudo code below.

```
image = new Image();
image.source = data.@thumb;
this.addChild(image);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, enlarge(image));
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, shrink(image));
```

When I mouse over the canvas, the enlarge function is called. However as soon as I move the mouse onto the image, or another child element, the MOUSE_OUT event is fired.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a way to disable this behaviour?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use [`MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:rollOver) and [`MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:rollOut) events instead.

From the Flash CS4 documentation:

> When the mouse enters the area of a display object or the area of any of its children from an object that is not one of its children, the display object dispatches the rollOver event. This is different behavior than that of the mouseOver event, which is dispatched each time the mouse enters the area of any child object of the display object container, even if the mouse was already over another child object of the display object container.

Comment: thanks, works great. However, if i open a combobox dropdown, it fires the 'application' ROLL_OUT... any idea ?

Comment: The combo box drop down is probably placed on the PopUpManager (if you're using Flex), or maybe on the stage itself (for anything else), which is likely outside of your application, so that's to be expected, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Josh that the `ROLL_OVER` events seem more appropriate to what you're doing.  However, you should be aware of the [`mouseChildren`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#mouseChildren) property of `flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer` (an ancestor of `UIComponent`).

Answer (score 1):

Rollout works for me. 
About the comboBox problem:
You can also check if the target of the event is a child from the container.