# in flex, onMouseOut is triggered on Child

Tags: apache-flex, mouseevent

In flex, I am using the following code:

mx:HBox id="box1" mouseOver="onBox('box1')" mouseOut="outofBox('box1')"
  // adding label
// closing HBox

onBox adds an image as child of box1:

var crossImage:Image = new Image();
crossImage.source =  "cross.png";
crossImage.id = "cross";

box1.addChild(crossImage);

and outofBox removes them.

I believe that image is child of HBox so mouseOut should not be triggered when I hover the mouse over image. But, the moment I hover my mouse pointer over image, mouseOut is triggered. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `mouseChildren` property of the container to `false`

Comment: It works !!! But the issue is if I set mouseChildren = false, then even I am not able to add event listeners to the images (children). For example, 

tickImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, tester); 

tickerImage is the child & now, tester is not being called. Any way to handle it?

Comment: You can remove the mouseChildren property (or set it to true) and add mouseover and mouseout events to your crossImage. Give them both the same event handler that does the following: `event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();`

Comment: it did not work. Im not sure if mouse out event ( of container ) wont be called before the events for the image

Comment: Found the following answer to my solution: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557028/how-to-stop-mouse-out-event-on-flex-canvas-firing-for-child-elements